# load picturebox image from database where image column may be null

Tags: c#, sql-server

there is the code for loading image from database and shows it in picture box. the problem is if there's no pic in a row it will encounter an error however i marked as allow nulls image column in database.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = sql;
    cmd.CommandText = ("select Image from Entry where EntryID =@EntryID");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Images");
    int count = ds.Tables["Images"].Rows.Count;

    if (count > 0)
    { 
    var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Images"].Rows[count - 1]["Image"]);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
    pictureBox1.Image= Image.FromStream(sream);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is `sream` a typo or do you have two different streams (`sream` & `var stream...`)?

Comment: unable to cast object of type 'system.dbnull' to type 'system.byte[]'

Comment: @aliprogrammer: that exception was a very big hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should check for `DbNull.Value`.

This should do the trick:

```
if (count > 0)
{ 
       if (ds.Tables["Images"].Rows[count - 1]["Image"] != DbNull.Value){
          var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Images"].Rows[count - 1]["Image"]);
          (MemoryStreamstream = new MemoryStream(data)
           pictureBox1.Image= Image.FromStream(sream);
       }
 }
```

You marked column id DB to accept null value so DB handles it but you also need do handle null in your application (you cannot cast DbNull value).

**Hint**

While using any kind of `Stream` you should use `Using` statement to dispose Stream after usage.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, you need to learn to use `using` blocks. This will ensure that the objects are Disposed of in a timely manner, even if an exception is thrown:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    using (
        var sql =
            new SqlConnection(
                @"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True")
        )
    {
        using (
            var cmd = new SqlCommand
                          {
                              Connection = sql,
                              CommandText =
                                  "select Image from Entry where EntryID = @EntryID"
                          })
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                "@EntryID",
                Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(ds, "Images");
            }
        }
    }

    var imagesTable = ds.Tables["Images"];
    var imagesRows = imagesTable.Rows;
    var count = imagesRows.Count;

    if (count <= 0)
        return;
    var imageColumnValue =
        imagesRows[count - 1]["Image"];
    if (imageColumnValue == DBNull.Value)
        return;

    var data = (Byte[]) imageColumnValue;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just check

```
if(ds.Tables["Images"].Rows[count - 1]["Image"]!=DbNull.Value)
{
   //you code of execution
}
else
{
    //display default image 
}
```